# Samsung 650TS large format touchscreen API support

Tags: api, sdk

A potential client is thinking of using a [Samsung 650TS 65" touchscreen](http://www.samsung.com/us/business/commercial-display-solutions/LH65TCPMBC/ZA) for a specific application, but other than "it connects to a PC via USB" I can't seem to find out anything about interfaces.

In particular, I'm looking to find out if it supports the (new) Microsoft Touch APIs under Windows 7, or if there is some other SDK available for it.  No doubt it will emulate a mouse, but that wouldn't give access to the multitouch or gesturing features under custom written software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that the 650TS uses drivers from [NextWindow](http://www.nextwindow.com/) for multitouch.  If you don't install those [drivers](http://www.nextwindow.com/nextwindow_support/windriver.html), it behaves like a standard USB mouse.  There is an SDK, available [here](http://www.nextwindow.com/nextwindow_support/api.html).